# Re-entrant code?

Tags: arduino

I am using the [Wire library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire) to move some data from a [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) to the Arduino.

The shield *always* puts out exactly 36 bytes (GPS device), but the Arduino sees two data transfers that together add up to 36 bytes. Not always the same count in each of the transfers, but always 36 bytes total. The `setup()` routine is re-run every time the data comes in.

It's as if the library is re-entering the Arduino application and screwing it royally.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the Arduino sketch - it's possible that the way the Wire library is being called is the cause of the issue here.

Comment: you need to elaborate the question properly.As i understand are you trying to syn gps time with RTC time???

Answer (score 3):

If `setUp()` is being run every time data comes in (and are you sure about this?) then this means that the Arduino is resetting/restarting for some reason. How are you powering the GPS shield? If it is glitching the power to the Arduino (drawing too much current perhaps) then that could cause a reset. It could also be something with your code using up too much memory. I'd look at the power issue first.

Comment: Thanks for the clue skinny.  I ran down the power requirements of the shield and it was within spec.  What the problem turned out to be was that I was building a String item and the code was running away sometime and the string became huge.  It filled memory and somehow was causing the setup() routine to be re-entered.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Wire.available`, note that it does not guarantee that it will return the number of bytes sent. You will need to call it repeatedly until it returns zero.

See an example in the [Arduino documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireRead).